# Advanced Search with tags and categories

Tags: search

Been scratching my head for the past day on how to implement search with multiple categories.

At the moment, I have product categories as a select dropdown which only allows to search in one category at a time. This is passing the value as a parameter. How do I go about searching with multiple categories (checkboxes) at once? Here's what I have so far.

Any ideas?

**search.html**

```
<form action="{{ url('food-suppliers/results') }}">
    <input type="search" name="query" placeholder="What are you looking for?" style="width: 100%;">

    <select name="supplier">
      <option value="">All Markets</option>
      {% set suppliers = craft.categories.group('suppliers') %}
      {% for supplier in suppliers %}
      <option value="{{ supplier.slug }}">{{ supplier.title }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>

    <select name="product">
      <option value="">All Products</option>
      {% set products = craft.categories.group('product') %}
      {% for product in products %}
      <option value="{{ product.slug }}">{{ product.title }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>

    <select name="delivery">
      <option value="">All Delivery</option>
      {% set deliveries = craft.categories.group('delivery') %}
      {% for delivery in deliveries %}
      <option value="{{ delivery.slug }}">{{ delivery.title }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>

    <div class="">
      <input type="checkbox" name="homeGrown" value="true">Home Grown<br/>
      <input type="checkbox" name="preparedProduce" value="true">Prepared Produce<br/>
      <input type="checkbox" name="redTractor" value="true">Red Tractor<br/>
    </div>

    <div class="">
      <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </div>

</form>
```

**results.html**

```
{% set query = craft.request.getParam('q') %}
{% set supplier = craft.request.getParam('supplier') %}
{% set product = craft.request.getParam('product') %}
{% set delivery = craft.request.getParam('delivery') %}

{% set homeGrownParam = craft.request.getParam('homeGrown') %}
{% set preparedProduceParam = craft.request.getParam('preparedProduce') %}
{% set redTractorParam = craft.request.getParam('redTractor') %}


{% set supplierCat = craft.categories.group('supplier').slug(supplier).first %}
{% set productCat = craft.categories.group('product').slug(product).first %}
{% set deliveryCat = craft.categories.group('delivery').slug(delivery).first %}


{% set supplierParam = supplier ? {targetElement: supplierCat} : '' %}
{% set productParam = product ? {targetElement: productCat} : '' %}
{% set deliveryParam = delivery ? {targetElement: deliveryCat} : '' %}


{% set entries = craft.entries.section('suppliers').relatedTo(productParam).relatedTo(deliveryParam).search(query).homeGrown(homeGrownParam).preparedProduce(preparedProduceParam).redTractor(redTractorParam) %}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before I answer your main question, I'm seeing a couple issues with what you’re currently doing that are worth correcting.

First, this code:

```
{% set supplierCat = craft.categories.group('supplier').slug(supplier).first %}
{% set productCat = craft.categories.group('product').slug(product).first %}
{% set deliveryCat = craft.categories.group('delivery').slug(delivery).first %}
```

should be replaced with:

```
{% set supplierCat = supplier ? craft.categories.group('supplier').slug(supplier).first %}
{% set productCat = product ? craft.categories.group('product').slug(product).first %}
{% set deliveryCat = delivery ? craft.categories.group('delivery').slug(delivery).first %}
```

in case any of the `supplier`/`product`/`delivery` params are blank.

Next, this code:

```
{% set supplierParam = supplier ? {targetElement: supplierCat} : '' %}
{% set productParam = product ? {targetElement: productCat} : '' %}
{% set deliveryParam = delivery ? {targetElement: deliveryCat} : '' %}
```

should be replaced with:

```
{% set supplierParam = supplierCat ? {targetElement: supplierCat} %}
{% set productParam = productCat ? {targetElement: productCat} %}
{% set deliveryParam = deliveryCat ? {targetElement: deliveryCat} %}
```

That way you will avoid unexpected behavior if a supplier/product/delivery was *posted*, but it had an invalid slug, and yielded no results. Also, the `: ''`s at the end are just not really necessary unless your *really* wanted them to be strings by default (no reason in this case though), as Twig will default the values to `null`, which is just as good.

Also, you can’t chain multiple `relatedTo` params together like this:

```twig
.relatedTo(productParam).relatedTo(deliveryParam)
```

When you do that, the second `relatedTo` param will just override the 1st one.

Instead you’d need to do something like:

```twig
{% set relationParams = [supplierParam, productParam, deliveryParam]|filter %}

{% set entries = craft.entries({
    section: 'suppliers',
    relatedTo: relationParams ? ['and']|merge(relationParams) : null,
    search: query,
    homeGrown: homeGrownParam,
    preparedProduce: preparedProduceParam,
    redTractor: redTractorParam
}) %}
```

*(I’m using the `{p1: v1, p2: v2}` syntax for setting the criteria params here for clarity, but you can use the `p1(v1).p2(v2)` chaining syntax instead if you prefer it.)*

---

With that out of the way…

To support searching for entries that are related to *multiple* suppliers/products/deliveries at the same time, the first thing you’ll need to do is update your search form. I know you said you want to go with checkboxes, but for simplicity’s sake I’ll demonstrate with multi-select boxes, since that’s closer to your original code and produces the same request param data.

For each of your `<select>`s, just append a `[]` to the input name and add the `multiple` attribute:

```twig
<select name="supplier[]" multiple>
...
<select name="product[]" multiple>
...
<select name="delivery[]" multiple>
...
```

In your search results template, change `.first` to `.find()` when fetching the categories:

```twig
{% set supplierCat = supplier ? craft.categories.group('supplier').slug(supplier).find() %}
{% set productCat = product ? craft.categories.group('product').slug(product).find() %}
{% set deliveryCat = delivery ? craft.categories.group('delivery').slug(delivery).find() %}
```

And assuming you want this to be an *inclusive* search (where only results with *all* of the selected suppliers should be included, etc.), you’ll need to prepend `'and'` to each of the `targetElement` arrays:

```twig
{% set supplierParam = supplierCat ? {targetElement: ['and']|merge(supplierCat)}l %}
{% set productParam = productCat ? {targetElement: ['and']|merge(productCat)} %}
{% set deliveryParam = deliveryCat ? {targetElement: ['and']|merge(deliveryCat)} %}
```

That’s it. The rest can stay the same.

Comment: There's a letter "l" at the end of this `{% set supplierParam = supplierCat ? {targetElement: supplierCat}l %}`, was that intended?

Comment: Works great! I just had to add a `selected` attribute to the first option in the select dropdown block. So the code looks something like this: `<option value="" selected>All Products</option>`

Comment: Interestingly, if I don't have the `selected` attribute on the first option of the three select boxes, it doesn't work? Why's that?

Comment: @Jose Just [updated the answer](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/posts/19258/revisions) to address the possibility of `supplier`/`product`/`delivery` params being blank.